# Sublime Text 3 no longer accessing environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, sublimetext3

I'm running Catalina 10.15.3 at the moment. Prior to upgrading, my python build in Sublime Text was accessing the environment variables no problem  with os.environ.get('A'). However, since the upgrade this is no longer true.

I've moved everything from my previous .bash_profile to my .zprofile. Additionally, if I launch python from zsh directly there is no issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _However, since the upgrade this is no longer true._ What happens instead? You might want to consider asking about this on https://forum.sublimetext.com/c/technical-support.

Comment: All calls return None. Thank you I can try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by launching Sublime Text 3 from a zsh shell.